# What is the difference between "AT+QIACT" and "AT+CGDCONT"

Tags: m2m

I have Quectel-EC21 LTE module but have a little problem to initialize.
I have really confused about "AT+QIACT" and "AT+CGDCONT" commands. 
Both actived PDP context but dont know what is the difference between.
I will have APN name, username and password. 
For that reason as I understand I may not use "AT+CGDCONT" command. 
Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but just in case anyone else has the same doubt.

"AT+CGDCONT" does not activate a PDP context but instead defines the PDP context with a context ID.

"AT+QIACT" write command activates the defined PDP context using the context ID.

Try activating a PDP context without defining it, you will get an error.